# I'm trying to import Open Data Kit Sc that i got from github, but i kept getting error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have imported a code from github but I am getting this error

Error:(12, 0) CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

and this is the link of the github

https://github.com/opendatakit/collect

and this is my gradle.build file

```
/**************************************************************************************************
 GRADLE CONFIG
 *************************************************************************************************/

if ((new File(gradle.local)).exists()) {
    apply from: gradle.local
} else {
    apply from: gradle.remote
}

applicationScripts.each {
    apply from: it
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

com.android.ddmlib.DdmPreferences.setTimeOut(60000)

android {
    // The following are set in the common.gradle file
    compileSdkVersion(compileVersion)
    buildToolsVersion(buildTools)

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId("org.odk.collect.android")
        minSdkVersion(9)
        targetSdkVersion(9)
        versionCode(1061)
        versionName("1.4.10")
    }

    productFlavors {
        demo {
        }

        master {
        }

        snapshot {
        }

        uitest {
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (shouldSign) {
                storeFile file(signStoreFilePath)
                storePassword signStorePass
                keyAlias signKeyAlias
                keyPassword signKeyPass
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled(minify)
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'

            if (shouldSign) {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
        debug {
            debuggable(true)
            testCoverageEnabled(testCoverage) // Allows AndroidTest JaCoCo reports to be generated
        }
    }

    packagingOptions { // Pick first occurrence of any files that cause conflicts, as defined in common.gradle
        packageList.each {
            pickFirst it
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility javaVersion
        targetCompatibility javaVersion
    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        cacheDynamicVersionsFor(0, 'seconds')
        cacheChangingModulesFor(0, 'seconds')
    }
    transitive = true
}

allprojects {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.1.32'

    // Testing-only dependencies
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: try removing this line : com.android.ddmlib.DdmPreferences.setTimeOut(60000)

Comment: You might want to create a Github issue for that specific repo.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before I got it to work.
Some things that I did that worked for me in Android Studio 2.1:

1. Install Google Play services using Android SDK manager
2. Installed git from here: https://git-scm.com/
3. In Android Studio, Goto Settings -> Plugins.
   Deactivate & remove github, keep only git plugin.
4. Then make sure your Android Studio can contact git
5. There were other stuff for which Android studio says it requires to download older versions. Download & install these as well.
6. Make sure gradle-config is at the right tag number as mentioned in the wiki.