# Getting error in the app after making custom fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have made a quiz app in which I have stored the questions in database and then taken out from the database in the form of list and I am making custom fragments to upload the questions from the arraylist but I am getting only 1 question on every fragment

This is my database code

```
package com.example.android.viewpager4;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "triviaQuiz";
    // tasks table name
    private static final String TABLE_QUEST = "quest";
    // tasks Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_QUES = "question";
    private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer"; //correct option
    private static final String KEY_OPTA= "opta"; //option a
    private static final String KEY_OPTB= "optb"; //option b
    private static final String KEY_OPTC= "optc"; //option c
    private SQLiteDatabase dbase;
    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        dbase=db;
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
                + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER+ " TEXT, "+KEY_OPTA +" TEXT, "
                +KEY_OPTB +" TEXT, "+KEY_OPTC+" TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(sql);        
        addQuestions();
        //db.close();
    }
    private void addQuestions()
    {
        Question q1=new Question("What is JP?","Jalur Pesawat", "Jack sParrow", "Jasa Programmer", "Jasa Programmer");
        this.addQuestion(q1);
        Question q2=new Question("where the JP place?", "Monas, Jakarta", "Gelondong, Bangun Tapan, bantul", "Gelondong, Bangun Tapan, bandul", "Gelondong, Bangun Tapan, bantul");
        this.addQuestion(q2);
        Question q3=new Question("who is CEO of the JP?","Usman and Jack", "Jack and Rully","Rully and Usman", "Rully and Usman" );
        this.addQuestion(q3);
        Question q4=new Question("what do you know about JP?", "JP is programmer home", "JP also realigy home", "all answer is true","all answer is true");
        this.addQuestion(q4);
        Question q5=new Question("what do you learn in JP?","Realigy","Programming","all answer is true","all answer is true");
        this.addQuestion(q5);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST);
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }
    // Adding new question
    public void addQuestion(Question quest) {
        //SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_QUES, quest.getQUESTION()); 
        values.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest.getANSWER());
        values.put(KEY_OPTA, quest.getOPTA());
        values.put(KEY_OPTB, quest.getOPTB());
        values.put(KEY_OPTC, quest.getOPTC());
        // Inserting Row
        dbase.insert(TABLE_QUEST, null, values);        
    }
    public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
        List<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
        dbase=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Question quest = new Question();
                quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
                quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
                quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(2));
                quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(3));
                quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(4));
                quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(5));
                quesList.add(quest);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // return quest list
        return quesList;
    }
    public int rowcount()
    {
        int row=0;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        row=cursor.getCount();
        return row;
    }
}
```

and this is my question.java class

```
package com.example.android.viewpager4;
public class Question {
    private int ID;
    private String QUESTION;
    private String OPTA;
    private String OPTB;
    private String OPTC;
    private String ANSWER;
    public Question()
    {
        ID=0;
        QUESTION="";
        OPTA="";
        OPTB="";
        OPTC="";
        ANSWER="";
    }
    public Question(String qUESTION, String oPTA, String oPTB, String oPTC,
                    String aNSWER) {

        QUESTION = qUESTION;
        OPTA = oPTA;
        OPTB = oPTB;
        OPTC = oPTC;
        ANSWER = aNSWER;
    }
    public int getID()
    {
        return ID;
    }
    public String getQUESTION() {
        return QUESTION;
    }
    public String getOPTA() {
        return OPTA;
    }
    public String getOPTB() {
        return OPTB;
    }
    public String getOPTC() {
        return OPTC;
    }
    public String getANSWER() {
        return ANSWER;
    }
    public void setID(int id)
    {
        ID=id;
    }
    public void setQUESTION(String qUESTION) {
        QUESTION = qUESTION;
    }
    public void setOPTA(String oPTA) {
        OPTA = oPTA;
    }
    public void setOPTB(String oPTB) {
        OPTB = oPTB;
    }
    public void setOPTC(String oPTC) {
        OPTC = oPTC;
    }
    public void setANSWER(String aNSWER) {
        ANSWER = aNSWER;
    }

}
```

and this is my custom fragment code

```
package com.example.android.viewpager4;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Vikas on 6/19/2016.
 */
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
    // Store instance variables
    private String question;
    private String radio_1,radio_2,radio_3;

    private int page;



    List<Question> quesList;

    int qid=0;
    Question currentQ;
    TextView txtQuestion;
    RadioButton rda, rdb, rdc;


    // newInstance constructor for creating fragment with arguments
    public static FirstFragment newInstance(int page, String question,String radio_1,String radio_2,String radio_3)
    {
        FirstFragment fragmentFirst = new FirstFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("someInt", page);
        args.putString("some_question", question);
        args.putString("some_option1",radio_1);
        args.putString("some_option1",radio_2);
        args.putString("some_option1",radio_3);

        fragmentFirst.setArguments(args);
        return fragmentFirst;
    }

    // Store instance variables based on arguments passed
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        DbHelper db = new DbHelper(getContext());
        quesList = db.getAllQuestions(); //get all the questions from database

        //getting the id of the question
        currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
        page = getArguments().getInt("someInt", 0);
        question = getArguments().getString("some_question",currentQ.getQUESTION());
        radio_1=getArguments().getString("some_option1", currentQ.getOPTA());
        radio_2=getArguments().getString("some_option2", currentQ.getOPTB());
        radio_3=getArguments().getString("some_option3", currentQ.getOPTC());
        qid++;
    }

    // Inflate the view for the fragment based on layout XML
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout, container, false);
        TextView question_view = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.question_id);
        question_view.setText(question);
        rda=(RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
        rdb=(RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
        rdc=(RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);
        rda.setText(radio_1);
        rdb.setText(radio_2);
        rdc.setText(radio_3);
        return view;
    }
}
```

and this my main activity.java

```
package com.example.android.viewpager4;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    List<Question> quesList;
    int qid=0;
    Question currentQ;



    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_layout);
        initialisePaging();
    }

    private void initialisePaging()
    {

        DbHelper db = new DbHelper(this);
        quesList = db.getAllQuestions(); //get all the questions from database

        //getting the id of the question
        currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
        List<FirstFragment> fragments =new Vector<FirstFragment>();
        fragments.add(FirstFragment.newInstance(0,currentQ.getQUESTION(),currentQ.getOPTA(),currentQ.getOPTB(),currentQ.getOPTC()));
        qid++;
        fragments.add(FirstFragment.newInstance(1,currentQ.getQUESTION(),currentQ.getOPTA(),currentQ.getOPTB(),currentQ.getOPTC()));
        qid++;
        fragments.add(FirstFragment.newInstance(2,currentQ.getQUESTION(),currentQ.getOPTA(),currentQ.getOPTB(),currentQ.getOPTC()));


        mPagerAdapter = new com.example.android.viewpager4.PagerAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(),fragments);
         ViewPager pager =(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
         pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    }
}
```

and this is my pageadapter.java

```
package com.example.android.viewpager4;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Vikas on 4/27/2016.
 */
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
   private List<FirstFragment> fragments;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<FirstFragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0)
    {
        return this.fragments.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }

}
```

and after this whole code I am getting the same question in every fragment please tell the changes which I should do  help me please fast thanks in advance

Comment: Please post error log?

Comment: You may save yourself some CPU time by passing the `Question` object directly into the `newInstance` method of the Fragment rather than the individual parts and querying the database for that object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have an error when you are trying to add the questions. You are adding the same questions again and again.

Change the below code :

```
 currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
        List<FirstFragment> fragments =new Vector<FirstFragment>();
        fragments.add(FirstFragment.newInstance(0,currentQ.getQUESTION(),currentQ.getOPTA(),currentQ.getOPTB(),currentQ.getOPTC()));
        qid++;
        fragments.add(FirstFragment.newInstance(1,currentQ.getQUESTION(),currentQ.getOPTA(),currentQ.getOPTB(),currentQ.getOPTC()));
        qid++;
        fragments.add(FirstFragment.newInstance(2,currentQ.getQUESTION(),currentQ.getOPTA(),currentQ.getOPTB(),currentQ.getOPTC()));
```

to

```
 currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
        List<FirstFragment> fragments =new Vector<FirstFragment>();
        fragments.add(FirstFragment.newInstance(0,currentQ.getQUESTION(),currentQ.getOPTA(),currentQ.getOPTB(),currentQ.getOPTC()));
        qid++;
currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
        fragments.add(FirstFragment.newInstance(1,currentQ.getQUESTION(),currentQ.getOPTA(),currentQ.getOPTB(),currentQ.getOPTC()));
        qid++;
currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
        fragments.add(FirstFragment.newInstance(2,currentQ.getQUESTION(),currentQ.getOPTA(),currentQ.getOPTB(),currentQ.getOPTC()));
```

Comment: hey man thanks for all your help but can you help me on this issue

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/37929898/… I really need help with this one else I will loose my internship so can you please help

Comment: Hey man thanks for the help  till now but I am having one more issue I have updated the same Custom fragments code but it is giving unfortunately your app has stopped please have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem originates at these three lines because all those keys are the same.

```
args.putString("some_option1",radio_1);
args.putString("some_option1",radio_2);
args.putString("some_option1",radio_3);
```

Some suggestions, try to restructure your adapter filling code like so

```
quesList = db.getAllQuestions();
for (int page = 0; page < quesList.size(); page++) {
    Question currentQ = quesList.get(page);
    // Is that page parameter needed in here?
    FirstFragment questionFragment = FirstFragment.newInstance(page, currentQ);
    fragments.add(questionFragment);
}

mPagerAdapter = new com.example.android.viewpager4.PagerAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(),fragments);
```

Notice that `currentQ` in the `newInstance` looks cleaner than `currentQ.getQUESTION(),currentQ.getOPTA(),currentQ.getOPTB(),currentQ.getOPTC()`

---

To prevent throwing around a List of Fragment objects, though, you could change the Adapter to take a List of Questions.

```
public class QuestionPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
   private List<Question> questions;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Question> questions) {
        super(fm);
        this.questions = questions;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        Question q = questions.get(position);
        // Is that int parameter needed here?
        return FirstFragment.newInstance(position, q);
    } 

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return this.questions.size();
    }
}
```

---

In both of those cases, you need to update the `newInstance` method.

```
public static FirstFragment newInstance(int page, Question q)
{
    FirstFragment fragmentFirst = new FirstFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("someInt", page); // Is this needed?
    args.putString("some_question", q.getQUESTION());
    args.putString("some_option1",q.getOPTA());
    args.putString("some_option2",q.getOPTB());
    args.putString("some_option3",q.getOPTC());

    fragmentFirst.setArguments(args);
    return fragmentFirst;
}
```

Then, to make that method look a little cleaner, you could make some `public static final String` fields for those argument strings just like you made for the database keys.

For example

```
public static final String ARG_QUESTION = "some_question";
public static final String ARG_OPT_A = "some_option1"; 
// etc.
```

Then

```
args.putString(ARG_QUESTION, q.getQUESTION());
args.putString(ARG_OPT_A, q.getOPTA());
// etc.
```

And

```
Bundle args = getArguments();
if (args != null) 
{
    question = args.getString(ARG_QUESTION, currentQ.getQUESTION());
    radio_1 = args.getString(ARG_OPT_A, currentQ.getOPTA());
    // etc.
}
```

---

And, finally, making `Question` implement `Parcelable` would be the best approach for passing data into the Fragment, that way, you don't need to get the `currentQ` back out of the database. (Because you are reading the entire database and only defaulting to the `qid` of 0 when those arguments are missing).

Comment: hey man thanks for all your help but can you help me on this issue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37929898/im-trying-to-import-open-data-kit-sc-that-i-got-from-github-but-i-kept-getting    I really need help with this one else I will loose my internship so can you please help

Comment: Sorry to hear that, but internships are a learning experience, not an at-will employment. Speak to your co-workers, if they can't help, your boss should understand your struggles and should be willing to assign you more manageable tasks.

Comment: Hey man thanks for the help till now but I am having one more issue I have updated the same Custom fragments code but it is giving unfortunately your app has stopped please have a look at it –

Comment: You've already accepted an answer here. Please post a new question with a [mcve]. I'm going to revert your edits because all you did was add a bunch of code and no stacktrace